# FHIR OperationOutcome to handle Consent

Tags: hl7-fhir

Refer to FHIR R4 and potentially R5.
We have the following scenario:

- Our client invokes our FHIR server, which returns a Bundle of the requested resources.
- Optionally, we can return an OperationOutcome in the Bundle in case of any issue.
- Some resources may be unauthorized or partially hidden because of a consent rule.

The issues are:

- There is no element inside `issue` that allows specifying issues for specific returned resources rather than an element expression (resource reference).
- No element allows referring to a hint (i.e., the Consent ID) that blocks a specific resource and probably allows unlocking it.

**Question: Is there any alternative response that enables the requested requirement?**

If you ask why the client would like to know that level of detail, there are several alternatives:

- The client is indeed another system that may complete the consent acceptance workflow or notify another module about the authorization requirement in an automated way.
- The client is a UI with the capability to lead the user to a resource authorization or authorization request page.
- The client may have a "break the glass" capability for certain Consent types

Answer (score 2):

If a resource was completely suppressed, there'd be no path for the OperationOutcome to point to.  All that can be done is display a generic warning indicating "Your search results may have been filtered to exclude certain results.  If you wish to access all records, please follow "break the glass process X".  If a resource was but redacted to show less than full information, that would be conveyed by the meta.security tag on the impacted issue, though you could also include a generic warning along the lines of "Some of the returned resources have been redacted for security/consent reasons.  If you need to see the complete content, please follow break-the-glass process X".

There is no standard break-the-glass process, so there is no standard set of elements conveyed in the OperationOutcome that allow more computably defining the interface for invoking it.  However, you could define extensions for your particular implementation space if that was useful.